# Following pattern for multiple sorts

Tags: javascript

Is the following pattern a good way to do multiple sorts, for example something along the lines of:

```
ORDER BY id ASC, name DESC, date ASC
```

```js
let people = [
    {Name: 'Alex', Age: 20},
    {Name: 'George', Age: 20},
    {Name: 'Tommy', Age: 11},
];
function cmpPeople(p1, p2) {
    // Age ASC
    if (p1.Age != p2.Age) {
        return p1.Age - p2.Age; // numeric fields can use subtraction
    } 
    // Name DESC
    else if (p1.Name != p2.Name) {
        return (p1.Name > p2.Name) ? -1 : 1;
    } 
    // Placeholder at end
    else return 0;
}
people.sort(cmpPeople);
console.log(people);
```

If not, what might be a cleaner way to chain together multiple sorts similar to how it's communicated with SQL?

Answer (score 1):

You could take an array of wanted keys and their order and iterate this array until a value is different from zero.

```js
const
    ASC = (a, b) => a > b || -(a < b),
    DESC = (a, b) => ASC(b, a),
    sortBy = columns => (a, b) => {
        let r = 0;

        columns.some(([key, fn]) => r = fn(a[key], b[key]));

        return r;
    }
    people = [{ Name: 'George', Age: 20 }, { Name: 'Alex', Age: 20 }, { Name: 'Tommy', Age: 11 }],
    order = [
        ['Age', ASC],
        ['Name', ASC]
    ];

people.sort(sortBy(order));

console.log(people);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: thanks for this. Could you explain how the `sortBy` part works, particularly `columns.some(([key, fn]) => r = fn(a[key], b[key]));` ?

Comment: the first is a destructuring of two values of the array and the body assigns the result of the comparing function to an outside declared variable `r`. if this value is not zero, it ends the iteration. if it is zero, both compared properties are the same and it take the next key and function for sorting until no more key/function pairs or getting a value which is not zero.

Answer (score 0):

What you have works, but here's a more succinct method perhaps. Using the arrow function, we can return a result without `return`. The first comparison returns the age difference unless it's zero, in which case it returns the second comparison which uses [localeCompare](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare)

```js
let people = [{Name: 'Alex', Age: 20}, {Name: 'George', Age: 20}, {Name: 'Tommy', Age: 11}];
const cmpPeople = (p1, p2) =>  p1.Age - p2.Age || p2.Name.localeCompare(p1.Name)
people.sort(cmpPeople);
console.log(people);
```

Answer (score 0):

The direction is right. The `else` is redundant. Also your comparator is very specific (contains business logic), you can't reuse it. I took it as an exercise and wrote generic comparator generator.

```js
let people = [
    { Name: "Alex", Age: 20 },
    { Name: "George", Age: 20 },
    { Name: "George", Age: 11 },
    { Name: "George", Age: 10 },
    { Name: "Tommy", Age: 11 },
];

function getComparator(fields) {
    return function (p1, p2) {
        for (let i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
            const v1 = p1[fields[i].field];
            const v2 = p2[fields[i].field];
            // It should work for numbers & strings in same way
            if (v1 > v2) return fields[i].order === "asc" ? 1 : -1;
            if (v1 < v2) return fields[i].order === "asc" ? -1 : 1;
        }
        return 0;
    };
}

const comparator = getComparator([
    { field: "Age", order: "asc" },
    { field: "Name", order: "desc" },
]);

people.sort(comparator);
console.log(people);
```